# Self-Hosted SignalR service won't work (start)

Tags: c#, signalr

I have SignalR server as Class Library Project and i referenced it in Console application (to simulate Windows service)

Here is code for SignalR

```
    public void Start()
    {
        try
        {
            string url = @"http://*:8081";
            using (WebApp.Start<Startup>(url))
            {
                Logger.Info(string.Format("Server running at {0}", url));
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Logger.Exception(ex, "Signalr start");
        }

        Run = true;

        Logger.Info("Starting Worker");
        workerThread = new Thread(() =>
        {
            Worker();
        });

        workerThread.Start();
    }
```

And here is Startup class

```
    public class Startup
    {
        Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.HubConfiguration hubconfiguration = null;

        public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            app.UseCors(CorsOptions.AllowAll);
            hubconfiguration = new HubConfiguration();
            hubconfiguration.EnableDetailedErrors = true;
            app.MapSignalR(hubconfiguration);
        }
    }
```

So, it is in one thread, and worker is in another. That seems fine since i did it in other project where it works. Worker thread isn't problem, it's just empty loop, not related to server in any way.

Problem is that server seems to "stop" - when i look with Netstat, nobody is listening on port 8081. There is no exception, it just silently fails.

I referenced Owin.Cors (and Owin.Host.HttpListener) in console project that actually runs this server but as I said, server just stops.

When I try to connect, client says "connection actively refused" and Putty (telnet) also says "can't connect".

Where is the problem? In a nutshell, i have Class Library with SignalR server that is referenced in Console project that runs it but server just wont work.

[edit]

And there is code of Console app that starts service

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        ServiceEngine Engine = new ServiceEngine();
        Engine.Start();
        Console.ReadKey();
        Engine.Stop();
    }
```

P.S. Sorry for my bad English.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, i solved it. Here was a problem:

```
    public static void Start()
    {
        try
        {
            string url = @"http://127.0.0.1:8081";
            WebApp.Start<Startup>(url);
            Logger.Info(string.Format("Server running at {0}", url));
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Logger.Exception(ex, "signalr start");
        }

        Run = true;

        Logger.Info("Starting Worker");
        workerThread = new Thread(() =>
        {
            Worker();
        });

        workerThread.Start();
    }
```

As you can see, using statement was removed and now it works fine! Interesting note - you can also make Singleton implementation of this "Engine", and it will also work.

Comment: @Matei_Radu, I will, when site allows to... It says in two days.

Answer (score 0):

I got Solution after doing lot of R & D. And Its a Simple change related to Account and Access Rights.

Use LocalSystem Account instead of LocalService Account in Service Installer.


You can do this either from doing below change in design view of your service installer:

Properties of Service Process Installer -> Set Account to LocalSystem.


or by doing below change in in designer.cs file of your service installer:

this.serviceProcessInstaller1.Account = System.ServiceProcess.ServiceAccount.LocalSystem;